# Formulae not working to split cells from multiple columns into multiple rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, split

I'm working on a large spreadsheet in Google Sheets with multiple columns that contain cells with lists separated by semicolons. I want to split by semicolon delimiters, while maintaining the surrounding values.

I tried [this script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/60861/google-sheets-split-multi-line-cell-into-new-rows-duplicate-surrounding-row-e) first, which does exactly what I need (just a different delimiter), and received an error:

> Invalid return. (line 17, file "Code")

Then I tried [this script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/60861/google-sheets-split-multi-line-cell-into-new-rows-duplicate-surrounding-row-e) but I wasn't able to modify it to point to the columns that I need to be split (/multiple columns).

Then I tried: [How to split single rows into multiple rows depending on whether one cell has values separated by commas or new lines in Google Sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35047496/split-single-rows-into-multiple-rows-depending-on-whether-one-cell-has-values-se) and saw this error:

> Unterminated regular expression literal.

I tried the second formula on that page and received:

> Script function not found: extract

I can actually run it for the entire sheet (split all semicolons in all columns) if that's easier. The range of my sheet is A1:BT223. The specific columns that contain values that need to be split are N-W, AL, BB, BD, and BH.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data please?

Comment: Here is some sample data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XFE2emhTnNd4HfR_nVG3J0l4ZywBRo-dsOTDznHze44/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The columns that I need to focus on are different in this sheet but as I mentioned above, really anywhere that has a semicolon can be split, if it's easier to apply the script to the entire sheet. If not, the columns that I need are: N-W, Y, AH, AY, BA, and BE. Thank you so much for taking a look!

Comment: Thanks. As far as I can see all three functions you tried only split for one column. How are you trying to handle rows where multiple columns have multiple values? For example if you have a row with `{"1;2", "a;b;c"}` Do you want something like `{1, "a"; 2, "b"; "", "c"}` or `{1, "a"; 2, "a"; 3, "a"; 1, "b"; 2, "b"; 3, "b"}`? (These are range literals, if you prefix them with a `=` in Sheets you will see the data in a table)

Comment: I'd love something like {1, "a"; 2, "a"; 3, "a"; 1, "b"; 2, "b"; 3, "b"}! That would be perfect, if possible.

Comment: @MarissaGlaserAltmann Did you resolve your problem or are you still looking for assistance?

Comment: @Tedinoz this was from 2016! All resolved and no longer working on this.

Comment: Ahh @MarissaGlaserAltmann.... misread 6 for 8. Apologies.