# How to extract a comma-separated cell and multiple other cells of a block onto a single row in new sheet block by block

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a Google Sheet with about 5000 products listed as per Source Sheet image below:
[Source Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S4d3.jpg)

[image]

I need to rearrange data to match destination Sheet image below:
[Destination Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtebB.jpg)

[image]

I have shared a few lines from the source and destination in this [Shared Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cCrBMkG_AbkoRWgBLM_ddevnZqgH2iPgW-ps1QUeEU4/edit?usp=sharing).

If anyone can assist I will be immensely grateful.

---

I found a similar question with answer that is close [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35047496/how-to-split-single-rows-into-multiple-rows-depending-on-whether-one-cell-has-va?rq=3) but I am not experienced in coding to modify this solution to meet my needs.

---

I tried the following code but realized this is going to get very messy with models having different numbers of products but I don't have the coding experience to find a neater solution...

```js
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  for (var counter = 2; counter <= 5000; counter = counter + 1) {
    cellBG = sheet1.getRange(counter,2).getBackground();
    if (cellBG == "#000000") {
      var brand = sheet1.getRange(counter,2).getValue();
    }
    if (cellBG == "#d8d8d8") {
      var machineType = sheet1.getRange(counter,3).getValue();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to have data from the first image in a table so that we can copy it into a spreadsheet

Comment: Hi Cooper - data from both images is available in the spreadsheet I shared here - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cCrBMkG_AbkoRWgBLM_ddevnZqgH2iPgW-ps1QUeEU4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Why do you want to use App Script instead of built-in formulas?

Comment: I am open to any and all suggestions but to be honest I didn't think it would be possible to do it with built-in formulas.

Comment: @DarylChambers: Looks doable. Enough chance to be doable that I wouldn't even be attracted to explore Apps Script solutions. I'll take a look to see if I can draft an answer in a bit

Comment: @DarylChambers: I did completed a solution. Since you are not specifically requiring Apps Script, I would include the generic Google Sheet tabs. (I made an edit and you are welcome to review it.) In the future, please always include example sheet in your question whenever the relative positional and formatting relations between cells is a part of the requirements. It would help testing a lot. And be sure to enable editing. That way, formulas can be directly shared with you without you having to check where they need to go. (And potentially make errors!) (Anonymous sharing is possible too.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a little difficult to post because the output is no longer rectangular.  The code queues in on the black background in column B to detect the beginning of a new table.  It assumes the first row has the manufacturer in column B.  The second has the machine type in column C. The third row has the year in column A and the models in Column C which are comma separated. The rest of the rows are spliced onto the end of each model row. I used A,B,C,D as my models list in each case I posted that string into the appropriate cell.

```
function findTables() {
  const hA = ["Manufacture", "Machine Type", "Model Number", "Year"];
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const rg = sh.getDataRange();
  const bs = rg.getBackgrounds();
  const vs = rg.getValues()
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(bs));
  const ob = vs.reduce((acc, r, i) => {
    let [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h] = r;
    if (bs[i][1] == "#000000") {
      acc.preA = [];
      acc.item = 0;
      acc.pA.push([]);
      acc.preA.push(b)
    } else if (acc.item == 0) {
      acc.item = 1;
      let = acc.idx = acc.pA.length - 1;
      acc.preA.push(c);
    } else if (acc.item == 1) {
      acc.item = 2;
      acc.modA = c.split(",");
      acc.modA.forEach((m, i) => {
        if (i == 0) {
          acc.preA.push(a);
        }
        if (i > 0) {
          acc.pA.push([])
        }
        acc.pA[acc.idx + i].splice(0, 0, acc.preA[0], acc.preA[1], m, acc.preA[2])
      });
    } else if (acc.item > 1) {
      acc.modA.forEach((m, i) => {
        acc.pA[acc.idx + i].splice(acc.pA[acc.idx + i].length, 0, b, c, d, e, f, g, h);
      });
    }
    return acc;
  }, { preA: [], modA: [], item: -1, pA: [], idx: 0 })
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(ob.pA).replace(/],/g, '],\n'));
  osh.clearContents();
  osh.appendRow(hA);
  ob.pA.forEach((r, i) => {
    osh.getRange(osh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, r.length).setValues([r])
  })
}
```

My Data:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 |
| 2 | A2 | Black Background | C2 | D2 | E2 | F2 | G2 | H2 |
| 3 | A3 | B3 | C3 | D3 | E3 | F3 | G3 | H3 |
| 4 | A4 | B4 | A,B,C,D | D4 | E4 | F4 | G4 | H4 |
| 5 | A5 | B5 | C5 | D5 | E5 | F5 | G5 | H5 |
| 6 | A6 | B6 | C6 | D6 | E6 | F6 | G6 | H6 |
| 7 | A7 | B7 | C7 | D7 | E7 | F7 | G7 | H7 |
| 8 | A8 | B8 | C8 | D8 | E8 | F8 | G8 | H8 |
| 9 | A9 | B9 | C9 | D9 | E9 | F9 | G9 | H9 |
| 10 | A10 | Black Background | C10 | D10 | E10 | F10 | G10 | H10 |
| 11 | A11 | B11 | C11 | D11 | E11 | F11 | G11 | H11 |
| 12 | A12 | B12 | A,B,C,D | D12 | E12 | F12 | G12 | H12 |
| 13 | A13 | B13 | C13 | D13 | E13 | F13 | G13 | H13 |
| 14 | A14 | B14 | C14 | D14 | E14 | F14 | G14 | H14 |
| 15 | A15 | B15 | C15 | D15 | E15 | F15 | G15 | H15 |
| 16 | A16 | B16 | C16 | D16 | E16 | F16 | G16 | H16 |
| 17 | A17 | Black Background | C17 | D17 | E17 | F17 | G17 | H17 |
| 18 | A18 | B18 | C18 | D18 | E18 | F18 | G18 | H18 |
| 19 | A19 | B19 | A,B,C,D | D19 | E19 | F19 | G19 | H19 |
| 20 | A20 | B20 | C20 | D20 | E20 | F20 | G20 | H20 |
| 21 | A21 | B21 | C21 | D21 | E21 | F21 | G21 | H21 |
| 22 | A22 | B22 | C22 | D22 | E22 | F22 | G22 | H22 |
| 23 | A23 | B23 | C23 | D23 | E23 | F23 | G23 | H23 |
| 24 | A24 | B24 | C24 | D24 | E24 | F24 | G24 | H24 |
| 25 | A25 | B25 | C25 | D25 | E25 | F25 | G25 | H25 |
| 26 | A26 | B26 | C26 | D26 | E26 | F26 | G26 | H26 |
| 27 | A27 | B27 | C27 | D27 | E27 | F27 | G27 | H27 |
| 28 | A28 | B28 | C28 | D28 | E28 | F28 | G28 | H28 |
| 29 | A29 | B29 | C29 | D29 | E29 | F29 | G29 | H29 |
| 30 | A30 | B30 | C30 | D30 | E30 | F30 | G30 | H30 |
| 31 | A31 | B31 | C31 | D31 | E31 | F31 | G31 | H31 |
| 32 | A32 | Black Background | C32 | D32 | E32 | F32 | G32 | H32 |
| 33 | A33 | B33 | C33 | D33 | E33 | F33 | G33 | H33 |
| 34 | A34 | B34 | A,B,C,D | D34 | E34 | F34 | G34 | H34 |
| 35 | A35 | B35 | C35 | D35 | E35 | F35 | G35 | H35 |
| 36 | A36 | B36 | C36 | D36 | E36 | F36 | G36 | H36 |
| 37 | A37 | B37 | C37 | D37 | E37 | F37 | G37 | H37 |
| 38 | A38 | B38 | C38 | D38 | E38 | F38 | G38 | H38 |
| 39 | A39 | B39 | C39 | D39 | E39 | F39 | G39 | H39 |
| 40 | A40 | B40 | C40 | D40 | E40 | F40 | G40 | H40 |
| 41 | A41 | B41 | C41 | D41 | E41 | F41 | G41 | H41 |

My output:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P | Q | R | S | T | U | V | W | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Manufacture | Machine Type | Model Number | Year |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | B2 | C3 | A | A4 | B5 | C5 | D5 | E5 | F5 | G5 | H5 | B6 | C6 | D6 | E6 | F6 | G6 | H6 | B7 | C7 | D7 | E7 | F7 | G7 | H7 | B8 | D8 | F8 | H8 | C9 | E9 | G9 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | B2 | C3 | B | A4 | B5 | C5 | D5 | E5 | F5 | G5 | H5 | B6 | C6 | D6 | E6 | F6 | G6 | H6 | B7 | C7 | D7 | E7 | F7 | G7 | H7 | B8 | D8 | F8 | H8 | C9 | E9 | G9 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | B2 | C3 | C | A4 | B5 | C5 | D5 | E5 | F5 | G5 | H5 | B6 | C6 | D6 | E6 | F6 | G6 | H6 | B7 | C7 | D7 | E7 | F7 | G7 | H7 | B8 | D8 | F8 | H8 | C9 | E9 | G9 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 5 | B2 | C3 | D | A4 | B5 | C5 | D5 | E5 | F5 | G5 | H5 | B6 | C6 | D6 | E6 | F6 | G6 | H6 | B7 | C7 | D7 | E7 | F7 | G7 | H7 | B8 | D8 | F8 | H8 | C9 | E9 | G9 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 6 | B10 | C11 | A | A12 | B13 | C13 | D13 | E13 | F13 | G13 | H13 | B14 | C14 | D14 | E14 | F14 | G14 | H14 | B15 | C15 | D15 | E15 | F15 | G15 | H15 | B16 | D16 | F16 | H16 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 7 | B10 | C11 | B | A12 | B13 | C13 | D13 | E13 | F13 | G13 | H13 | B14 | C14 | D14 | E14 | F14 | G14 | H14 | B15 | C15 | D15 | E15 | F15 | G15 | H15 | B16 | D16 | F16 | H16 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 8 | B10 | C11 | C | A12 | B13 | C13 | D13 | E13 | F13 | G13 | H13 | B14 | C14 | D14 | E14 | F14 | G14 | H14 | B15 | C15 | D15 | E15 | F15 | G15 | H15 | B16 | D16 | F16 | H16 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 9 | B10 | C11 | D | A12 | B13 | C13 | D13 | E13 | F13 | G13 | H13 | B14 | C14 | D14 | E14 | F14 | G14 | H14 | B15 | C15 | D15 | E15 | F15 | G15 | H15 | B16 | D16 | F16 | H16 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 10 | B17 | C18 | A | A19 | B20 | C20 | D20 | E20 | F20 | G20 | H20 | B21 | C21 | D21 | E21 | F21 | G21 | H21 | B22 | C22 | D22 | E22 | F22 | G22 | H22 | B23 | D23 | F23 | H23 | C24 | E24 | G24 | B25 | D25 | F25 | H25 | C26 | E26 | G26 | B27 | D27 | F27 | H27 | C28 | E28 | G28 | B29 | D29 | F29 | H29 | C30 | E30 | G30 | B31 | D31 | F31 | H31 |
| 11 | B17 | C18 | B | A19 | B20 | C20 | D20 | E20 | F20 | G20 | H20 | B21 | C21 | D21 | E21 | F21 | G21 | H21 | B22 | C22 | D22 | E22 | F22 | G22 | H22 | B23 | D23 | F23 | H23 | C24 | E24 | G24 | B25 | D25 | F25 | H25 | C26 | E26 | G26 | B27 | D27 | F27 | H27 | C28 | E28 | G28 | B29 | D29 | F29 | H29 | C30 | E30 | G30 | B31 | D31 | F31 | H31 |
| 12 | B17 | C18 | C | A19 | B20 | C20 | D20 | E20 | F20 | G20 | H20 | B21 | C21 | D21 | E21 | F21 | G21 | H21 | B22 | C22 | D22 | E22 | F22 | G22 | H22 | B23 | D23 | F23 | H23 | C24 | E24 | G24 | B25 | D25 | F25 | H25 | C26 | E26 | G26 | B27 | D27 | F27 | H27 | C28 | E28 | G28 | B29 | D29 | F29 | H29 | C30 | E30 | G30 | B31 | D31 | F31 | H31 |
| 13 | B17 | C18 | D | A19 | B20 | C20 | D20 | E20 | F20 | G20 | H20 | B21 | C21 | D21 | E21 | F21 | G21 | H21 | B22 | C22 | D22 | E22 | F22 | G22 | H22 | B23 | D23 | F23 | H23 | C24 | E24 | G24 | B25 | D25 | F25 | H25 | C26 | E26 | G26 | B27 | D27 | F27 | H27 | C28 | E28 | G28 | B29 | D29 | F29 | H29 | C30 | E30 | G30 | B31 | D31 | F31 | H31 |
| 14 | B32 | C33 | A | A34 | B35 | C35 | D35 | E35 | F35 | G35 | H35 | B36 | C36 | D36 | E36 | F36 | G36 | H36 | B37 | C37 | D37 | E37 | F37 | G37 | H37 | B38 | D38 | F38 | H38 | C39 | E39 | G39 | B40 | D40 | F40 | H40 | C41 | E41 | G41 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 15 | B32 | C33 | B | A34 | B35 | C35 | D35 | E35 | F35 | G35 | H35 | B36 | C36 | D36 | E36 | F36 | G36 | H36 | B37 | C37 | D37 | E37 | F37 | G37 | H37 | B38 | D38 | F38 | H38 | C39 | E39 | G39 | B40 | D40 | F40 | H40 | C41 | E41 | G41 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 16 | B32 | C33 | C | A34 | B35 | C35 | D35 | E35 | F35 | G35 | H35 | B36 | C36 | D36 | E36 | F36 | G36 | H36 | B37 | C37 | D37 | E37 | F37 | G37 | H37 | B38 | D38 | F38 | H38 | C39 | E39 | G39 | B40 | D40 | F40 | H40 | C41 | E41 | G41 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 17 | B32 | C33 | D | A34 | B35 | C35 | D35 | E35 | F35 | G35 | H35 | B36 | C36 | D36 | E36 | F36 | G36 | H36 | B37 | C37 | D37 | E37 | F37 | G37 | H37 | B38 | D38 | F38 | H38 | C39 | E39 | G39 | B40 | D40 | F40 | H40 | C41 | E41 | G41 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Here's and example with different model numbers:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P | Q | R | S | T | U | V | W | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Manufacture | Machine Type | Model Number | Year |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | B2 | C3 | A | A4 | B5 | C5 | D5 | E5 | F5 | G5 | H5 | B6 | C6 | D6 | E6 | F6 | G6 | H6 | B7 | C7 | D7 | E7 | F7 | G7 | H7 | B8 | D8 | F8 | H8 | C9 | E9 | G9 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | B2 | C3 | B | A4 | B5 | C5 | D5 | E5 | F5 | G5 | H5 | B6 | C6 | D6 | E6 | F6 | G6 | H6 | B7 | C7 | D7 | E7 | F7 | G7 | H7 | B8 | D8 | F8 | H8 | C9 | E9 | G9 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | B2 | C3 | C | A4 | B5 | C5 | D5 | E5 | F5 | G5 | H5 | B6 | C6 | D6 | E6 | F6 | G6 | H6 | B7 | C7 | D7 | E7 | F7 | G7 | H7 | B8 | D8 | F8 | H8 | C9 | E9 | G9 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 5 | B2 | C3 | D | A4 | B5 | C5 | D5 | E5 | F5 | G5 | H5 | B6 | C6 | D6 | E6 | F6 | G6 | H6 | B7 | C7 | D7 | E7 | F7 | G7 | H7 | B8 | D8 | F8 | H8 | C9 | E9 | G9 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 6 | B2 | C3 | E | A4 | B5 | C5 | D5 | E5 | F5 | G5 | H5 | B6 | C6 | D6 | E6 | F6 | G6 | H6 | B7 | C7 | D7 | E7 | F7 | G7 | H7 | B8 | D8 | F8 | H8 | C9 | E9 | G9 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 7 | B10 | C11 | A | A12 | B13 | C13 | D13 | E13 | F13 | G13 | H13 | B14 | C14 | D14 | E14 | F14 | G14 | H14 | B15 | C15 | D15 | E15 | F15 | G15 | H15 | B16 | D16 | F16 | H16 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 8 | B10 | C11 | B | A12 | B13 | C13 | D13 | E13 | F13 | G13 | H13 | B14 | C14 | D14 | E14 | F14 | G14 | H14 | B15 | C15 | D15 | E15 | F15 | G15 | H15 | B16 | D16 | F16 | H16 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 9 | B10 | C11 | C | A12 | B13 | C13 | D13 | E13 | F13 | G13 | H13 | B14 | C14 | D14 | E14 | F14 | G14 | H14 | B15 | C15 | D15 | E15 | F15 | G15 | H15 | B16 | D16 | F16 | H16 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 10 | B10 | C11 | D | A12 | B13 | C13 | D13 | E13 | F13 | G13 | H13 | B14 | C14 | D14 | E14 | F14 | G14 | H14 | B15 | C15 | D15 | E15 | F15 | G15 | H15 | B16 | D16 | F16 | H16 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 11 | B10 | C11 | E | A12 | B13 | C13 | D13 | E13 | F13 | G13 | H13 | B14 | C14 | D14 | E14 | F14 | G14 | H14 | B15 | C15 | D15 | E15 | F15 | G15 | H15 | B16 | D16 | F16 | H16 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 12 | B10 | C11 | F | A12 | B13 | C13 | D13 | E13 | F13 | G13 | H13 | B14 | C14 | D14 | E14 | F14 | G14 | H14 | B15 | C15 | D15 | E15 | F15 | G15 | H15 | B16 | D16 | F16 | H16 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 13 | B10 | C11 | G | A12 | B13 | C13 | D13 | E13 | F13 | G13 | H13 | B14 | C14 | D14 | E14 | F14 | G14 | H14 | B15 | C15 | D15 | E15 | F15 | G15 | H15 | B16 | D16 | F16 | H16 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 14 | B17 | C18 | A | A19 | B20 | C20 | D20 | E20 | F20 | G20 | H20 | B21 | C21 | D21 | E21 | F21 | G21 | H21 | B22 | C22 | D22 | E22 | F22 | G22 | H22 | B23 | D23 | F23 | H23 | C24 | E24 | G24 | B25 | D25 | F25 | H25 | C26 | E26 | G26 | B27 | D27 | F27 | H27 | C28 | E28 | G28 | B29 | D29 | F29 | H29 | C30 | E30 | G30 | B31 | D31 | F31 | H31 |
| 15 | B17 | C18 | B | A19 | B20 | C20 | D20 | E20 | F20 | G20 | H20 | B21 | C21 | D21 | E21 | F21 | G21 | H21 | B22 | C22 | D22 | E22 | F22 | G22 | H22 | B23 | D23 | F23 | H23 | C24 | E24 | G24 | B25 | D25 | F25 | H25 | C26 | E26 | G26 | B27 | D27 | F27 | H27 | C28 | E28 | G28 | B29 | D29 | F29 | H29 | C30 | E30 | G30 | B31 | D31 | F31 | H31 |
| 16 | B17 | C18 | C | A19 | B20 | C20 | D20 | E20 | F20 | G20 | H20 | B21 | C21 | D21 | E21 | F21 | G21 | H21 | B22 | C22 | D22 | E22 | F22 | G22 | H22 | B23 | D23 | F23 | H23 | C24 | E24 | G24 | B25 | D25 | F25 | H25 | C26 | E26 | G26 | B27 | D27 | F27 | H27 | C28 | E28 | G28 | B29 | D29 | F29 | H29 | C30 | E30 | G30 | B31 | D31 | F31 | H31 |
| 17 | B17 | C18 | D | A19 | B20 | C20 | D20 | E20 | F20 | G20 | H20 | B21 | C21 | D21 | E21 | F21 | G21 | H21 | B22 | C22 | D22 | E22 | F22 | G22 | H22 | B23 | D23 | F23 | H23 | C24 | E24 | G24 | B25 | D25 | F25 | H25 | C26 | E26 | G26 | B27 | D27 | F27 | H27 | C28 | E28 | G28 | B29 | D29 | F29 | H29 | C30 | E30 | G30 | B31 | D31 | F31 | H31 |
| 18 | B32 | C33 | A | A34 | B35 | C35 | D35 | E35 | F35 | G35 | H35 | B36 | C36 | D36 | E36 | F36 | G36 | H36 | B37 | C37 | D37 | E37 | F37 | G37 | H37 | B38 | D38 | F38 | H38 | C39 | E39 | G39 | B40 | D40 | F40 | H40 | C41 | E41 | G41 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 19 | B32 | C33 | B | A34 | B35 | C35 | D35 | E35 | F35 | G35 | H35 | B36 | C36 | D36 | E36 | F36 | G36 | H36 | B37 | C37 | D37 | E37 | F37 | G37 | H37 | B38 | D38 | F38 | H38 | C39 | E39 | G39 | B40 | D40 | F40 | H40 | C41 | E41 | G41 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 20 | B32 | C33 | C | A34 | B35 | C35 | D35 | E35 | F35 | G35 | H35 | B36 | C36 | D36 | E36 | F36 | G36 | H36 | B37 | C37 | D37 | E37 | F37 | G37 | H37 | B38 | D38 | F38 | H38 | C39 | E39 | G39 | B40 | D40 | F40 | H40 | C41 | E41 | G41 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 21 | B32 | C33 | D | A34 | B35 | C35 | D35 | E35 | F35 | G35 | H35 | B36 | C36 | D36 | E36 | F36 | G36 | H36 | B37 | C37 | D37 | E37 | F37 | G37 | H37 | B38 | D38 | F38 | H38 | C39 | E39 | G39 | B40 | D40 | F40 | H40 | C41 | E41 | G41 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Answer (score 0):

The solution is the easiest if you allow for a helper tab.

Create a new sheet called "helper".

In `helper!A1`, input

```js
=vstack(reduce(tocol(,1),Sheet1!A:A,lambda(a,c,if(isblank(c),a,
            vstack(a,hstack(row(c),counta(split(offset(c,0,column(Sheet1!C:C)-column(c)),","))))))),  
 hstack(index(sort(if(isblank(Sheet1!B:B),,row(Sheet1!B:B)),1,false),1,1)+3,))
```

In `helper!A3`, input

```js
=index(sort(if(isblank(B:B),,row(B:B)),1,false),1,1)
```

*You can substitute these helper columns via `let` if you have a reason in your actual application to centralize all the formulas. As is, we have a fixed number (7) of formulas and the product sheet is already allowed to grow dynamically. Future modifications would already be centralized so I am leaving the solution as is and with the helper sheet.*

In your output sheet, `A2` to `E2`, input the followings in order

```js
=reduce(tocol(,1),indirect("helper!A1:A"&helper!C1),lambda(a,c,
   vstack(a,arrayformula(if(sequence(offset(c,0,1)),index(Sheet1!B:B,c-2))))))

=reduce(tocol(,1),indirect("helper!A1:A"&helper!C1),lambda(a,c,
   vstack(a,arrayformula(if(sequence(offset(c,0,1)),index(Sheet1!C:C,c-1))))))

=reduce(tocol(,1),chooserows(Sheet1!C:C,indirect("helper!A1:A"&helper!C1)),lambda(a,c,
   vstack(a,tocol(split(c,","),1))))

=reduce(tocol(,1),indirect("helper!A1:A"&helper!C1),lambda(a,c,
   vstack(a,arrayformula(if(sequence(offset(c,0,1)),index(Sheet1!A:A,c))))))

=reduce(tocol(,1),indirect("helper!A1:A"&helper!C1),lambda(aa,cc,
   vstack(aa, arrayformula(if(sequence(offset(cc,0,1)),
     reduce(torow(,1),chooserows(Sheet1!$B:$H,sequence(offset(cc,1,0)-cc-3,1,cc+1,1)),
            lambda(a,c,hstack(a,c))))))))
```

The result is the desired output as shown below.

As always, the formatting from your example sheet needs to be strictly adhered to in your actual input sheet. To highlight a few:

- product blocks have no other rows between them.
- product blocks always starts a brand row in Column C, followed by type row in Column B, and model year + model number row in Column A & C respectively, and finally ends with product info rows in Column B-H.
- model numbers form a comma-separated list with no space in between.

Of course, you can also modify the corresponding formula if any of the above is changed. The list above is meant to highlight what one needs to be aware of.

---

helper sheet:

[image]

output sheet:

[image]

---

**Explanations**:

- `helper!A:A` extracts the row numbers of the years in your product sheet, which are later used to identify individual blocks. An additional artificial row to keep track of the number of rows in the last block

`index(sort(row(...),1,false),1,1)` is a technique to extract the row index of the last row of the input range. `if(isblank(...` is a technique to constrain an infinite range to its last row with content. Infinite range here means your product sheet is allowed to grow dynamically.

- `helper!B:B` stores the number of distinct model numbers per block as defined by `counta(split(...`

`offset` usage allows us to refer to Column C of your product sheet, where the model numbers are, while scanning through Column A.

- `helper!C1` stores the number of blocks, which is later used to enable ranges with unspecified end row via `indirect`

Same technique using `sort` as before.

The reason to use `indirect` over, for example, `array_constrain`, is to enable the use of `offset` in subsequent formulas, which is the most convenient for the purposes of this application.

- Column `A`, `B`, `D` of your output all functions the same way: we repeat each desired field by N number of times where N = the number of distinct models for that block using an `if(sequence(...),rows)` technique; and then vertically concatenate and display the results using `reduce(... vstack(...`.

Remember, the position of the desired field and corresponding N have been figured out and stored in `helper!A:B`.

- Column `C` functions similarly as the previous component except the content to vertically concatenate comes from `split`.

The number of rows (the **N**s) will match since each N comes from counting the number of distinct models via `split` to begin with.

- Column `E` is the actual product info. The repeat part functions in the same way as the previous components. The difference is in that the content needs to be extracted from the product sheet and horizontally concatenated with `reduce(... hstack(...`.

The `if(sequence(...),rows)` technique works to repeat 2D array as well as 1D. ie. It works to repeat multi-column rows as well as repeat cells by row).

The product info is extracted with `chooserows` where the row numbers are deduced from the row numbers between the model years. ie. For each product block, they start 1 row after model year, until 3 rows before the next model year.